# How to ignore home key to redirect the selected page while using intent chooser to open pdf file?

Tags: android

In our application, we have two buttons as my script and my document. If log in gets success we get some PDF from sever and sending those file to my script. From local storage we are opening PDF files through our application. For this we have used intent choser in `manifest.` Suppose I'm on my document view and if I clicked on back key of device it's working fine. But in case if I pressed home key it's redirecting to my document view again.

I checked this in on Resume, its getting same `Intent.ACTION_VIEW.`

Comment: put your code here. and hopefully activity launch mode will help you.

Comment: in manifest i have used <activity android:name="com.data.activities.ABCActivity"       android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|screenLayout" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /><data android:scheme="file" /><data android:mimeType="application/pdf" /><data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: do you have some code in onResume?

Comment: please put this in your question

Comment: @Override
 protected void onResume() {

  super.onResume();
  final Intent intent = getIntent();
  final String action = intent.getAction();
  
  

  if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
//some code to open file from local storage
  } else {  // not in open view.                                                   }

Comment: Its clear from code. In onResume you launch "Intent.ACTION_VIEW"?

Comment: why you put this code in your onResume?

Comment: because if i open local pdf file and in case of beack key oncreate on resume flow will call and if home key directly on resume will get called.

Comment: I post answar let me know if it doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in your activity tag in manifest file.

let me know if it helps you.

Comment: By clicking home key its working fine that redirection issue has resolved but Its giving intent.getAction() as a null value so that intent chooser is not working properly to send file to application.

Comment: I hope you are doing something in a wrong manner. give me some more detail of your activity flow

Comment: manifest code  <activity
            android:name="com.data.activities.MainActivity"         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|screenLayout"android:launchMode="singleTask"android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" ><intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /><data android:scheme="file" /><data android:mimeType="application/pdf" /><data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" /></intent-filter></activity>

Comment: @Aarushi that's fine. but in `onResume` `getIntent()` shows that you are passing some values from back activity.

Comment: @Override
 protected void onResume() {

  super.onResume();
  final Intent intent = getIntent();
  final String action = intent.getAction();

  if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {   
uri2 = intent.getData();
uri = uri2.toString();File objFile = newFile(uri2.getPath()); } else{// different view } this is only code what i am doing.

Comment: No @praveen. Its my first activity.Its returning same view if i clicked Home activity and open the file explorer its redirect me to my document view i.e. onresume if condition is getting called.

Comment: I can not help you without knowing how you are doing in your onCreate method